# calling methods of subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I'm trying to learn inheritance. I have a superclass called Shape with getColor and getFilled methods. I then have 3 subclasses called Triangle, Rectangle and Circle. In each of the subclasses I have methods getPerimeter and getArea. Each shape has a subclass that extends the superclass. I then create an ArrayList and add a Triangle, Rectangle and Circle. I can call the getColor and getFilled superclass methods but run into a problem when trying to call the getPerimeter and getArea method that are created in the subclass. I think I have a misunderstanding of subclass and superclass. Here is my code:

Shape superclass

```
public class Shape
{
    // instance variables
    public String color; // color of shape
    public boolean filled; // shape fill status

    public Shape()
    {
        // initialize instance variables
        color = "";
        filled = false;
    }
    
    public String getColor()
    {
        return color;
    }
    
    public boolean getFilled()
    {
        return filled;
    }
    
    public String toString()
    {
        return getClass().getName();
    }
}
```

Triangle (did not include here the Circle/Rectangle because they are basically the same as triangle)

```
public class Triangle extends Shape
{
    // instance variables
    private double side1;
    private double side2;
    private double side3;

    public Triangle(String color, boolean filled, double side1, double side2, double side3)
    {
        // initialize instance variables
        super.color = color;
        super.filled = filled;
        this.side1 = side1;
        this.side2 = side2;
        this.side3 = side3;
    }
    
    public double getPerimeter() {
        return this.side1 + this.side2 + this.side3;
    }
    
    public double getArea() {
        return (this.side2 / 2.0) * this.side1;
    }
}
```

Tester:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Tester
{
    
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>(); // create new array list of shapes
        shapes.add(new Triangle("white", true, 3.0, 2.5, 2.0)); // Add new triangle to shapes list
        shapes.add(new Rectangle("red", true, 2.0, 4.0)); // Add new rectangle to shapes list
        shapes.add(new Circle("yellow", false, 1.0)); // Add new circle to shapes list
        System.out.println("Starting shapes\n");
        for (Shape shape: shapes) // loop through shapes
        {
            System.out.println(shape.toString()
                +"[color="+shape.getColor()+", filled="+shape.getFilled()+"]"
                ); // print out string of shape/color/fill
            System.out.println("Perimeter: "+shape.getPerimeter()); // print out perimeter
            System.out.println("Area: "+shape.getArea()); // print out perimeter
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

I expected to be able to call shape.getPerimeter() and shape.getArea() from the subclasses.

Comment: If you want to call a child's method you will have to downcast the shape to the specific child type. Google downcasting java

Comment: All you know in that loop is that `shape` is a `Shape`. That class does not have `getPerimeter` and `getArea`.

Comment: If all implementations of `Shape` must have these methods, you can define them as [abstract methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) and make `Shape` an abstract class.

Comment: I guess I didn't ask a clear enough question. In what way do I need to change the code to make the calls to getPerimeter and getArea accessible to a method call?

Comment: Please have a look at how to write a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

Added getPerimeter() and getArea() to parent Shape class, then added @Override in front of public class getPerimeter( and public class getArea( in all of the subclasses. Solved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).